# In Android, is one task executed using all the cores of the device or just one only?

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, multicore, multitasking

If I have an 8 cores device, and running a huge task like this:

```
int sum=1;
for (int i=0; i<99999999; i++){
    sum=(int)(sum+sum);
}
```

Will this task be executed using the 8 cores of the device? or just one? I want to know if you should manually create 8 threads with 1/8 of the task for each core or you can do your huge task in just a thread because the OS will be capable of use the eight cores at once with your task.

Comment: A single thread will be executed by a single core only

Comment: how can you distribute the task between the 8 cores? using manually 8 threads? it is a little frustrating. This should be handled automatically by the OS.

Comment: You are talking about 'Parallel Computing' here. Not as easy as it sounds: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing

Comment: Sorry, no disrespect, but how do you have 8k+ rep, all in android / java, and not know that a single thread will only be executed on a single core?

Answer (score 1):

Your example will execute by single core only.

If you want to use multiple cores you should devide your program on separate threads. 
If you want to make parallel execution with threads better, you should use `Executors` and do not set pool limit or set it to be equal cores.

Sometimes cores are not equal and some of them are using by OS only, so you its better to know how much you can use.You can see how much cores are available with this:

```
int n = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
```

Comment: that function works perfectly with newest android versions?

Comment: it should, its basic Java function, available since API lvl1  https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#availableProcessors()

Comment: edited, anyway this function should work in any version of android, just checked on my RedMi Note2